# Show that two right cosets $Hx$ and $Hy$ of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ are equal iff $yx^{-1}$ is an element of H

Tags: group-theory

> Show that two right cosets $Hx$ and $Hy$ of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ are
>   equal if and only if $yx^{-1}$ is an element of H

Suppose $Hx=Hy$. Then $h_1x=h_2y$ for some $h_1$ and $h_2$ in $H$. Hence, $y=h_2^{-1}h_1x$

It follows that $yx^{-1}=h_2^{-1}h_1 $ 
Since $H$ is closed under the binary operation induced from $G$ then there exists $h'\in H$ such that $h'=h_2^{-1}h_1$

$\therefore yx^{-1}=h'$ so $yx^{-1} \in H $

Now suppose $yx^{-1}\in H $ Then there is an $h\in H$ such that $h=yx^{-1} $ $\iff hx=y$

Comment: You want to prove both implications. So you start by assuming $Hx=Hy$ then you show $yx^{-1}\in H$. Then you assume $yx^{-1}\in H$ and show $Hx=Hy$. Where specifically are you stuck, and with which part of the proof?

Comment: To show that $Hx = Hy$, it would be enough to show that $y \in Hx$.  This is because two cosets are either equal or disjoint.

Comment: Oh, I completely ignored the structure of the question, it's an iff question.

Comment: I edited it now @Dave

Comment: $Hx=Hy$ does not imply $x=y$ in general. For example, take $G=S_3$ and $H=\{e,(12)\}$. Then $He=H(12)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you give for the implication $yx^{-1}\in H\implies Hx=Hy$ works, provided you mention the reasoning as given by Matthew in the comments (i.e. it suffices to show $y\in Hx$ to show $Hx=Hy$ since two right cosets of $H$ in $G$ are either identical or disjoint).

To get you started with the implication $Hx=Hy\implies yx^{-1}\in H$ consider the following. Suppose $Hx=Hy$. Then $h_1x=h_2y$ for some $h_1$ and $h_2$ in $H$. Hence, $y=h_2^{-1}h_1x$. You want to show $yx^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Is the first one OK now?

Comment: The first part is good now. I would argue that the final step you do (i.e. writing $h_2^{-1}h_1=h'$) is unnecessary. I would just write $yx^{-1}=h_2^{-1}h_1\in H$, but this is just me, and the extra detail you add certainly doesn't hurt.

Comment: So, how do I show now that $y\in Hx $ from the final step $ y=hx? $

Comment: Well that is immediate from the definition of $Hx$. $Hx$ is the set of all elements of the form $hx$ where $h\in H$. So you are able to write $y=hx$ where $h\in H$, so clearly $y\in Hx$.

Comment: Oh, definitely :)